# Executing binary on iPhone

Tags: c, objective-c, iphone

I wonder how a can include an pre-compiled binary in an iPhone application.

I can't compile it inside XCode, I can only have the binary compiled for arm.

I tried the execve function, but always reports "Operation not supported", I thought it was something with file permissions, but even setting +x perm got the same error...

(Obviously it works on Simulator using an i386 binary)

any hints?

Comment: You should vote for which anser you think is correct (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot. Launching separate processes is not supported on the iPhone.